# Does JSSoup support extracting text?

Tags: beautifulsoup, jssoup

Does [JSSoup](https://github.com/chishui/JSSoup) support extracting text similar to Beautiful Soup `soup.findAll(text=True)`?

The documentation does not provide any information about this use case, but seems to me that there should be a way.

To clarify what I want is to grab all visible text from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `beautiful soup` you can extract text in different ways with `find_all(text=True)` but also with `.get_text()` or `.text`.

`JSSoup` works similar to `beautiful soup` - To extract all visible text just call `.get_text()`, `.text` or `string` on your `soup`.

#### Example (jssoup)

```
var soup = new JSSoup('<html><head><body>text<p>ptext</p></body></head></html>');
soup.get_text('|')
// 'text|ptext'

soup.get_text('|').split('|')
// ['text','ptext']
```

#### Example (beautiful soup)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<html><head><body>text<p>ptext</p></body></head></html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") 
print(soup.get_text('|').split('|'))
```

#### Output

```
['text','ptext']
```

Comment: Thanks @HedgeHog, however soup.findAll returns an array, which makes further processing easier for me.

Comment: Okay, an array is just a step away `soup.get_text('|').split('|')` - This should convert your text into an array.

Comment: Sounds about right. Syntax in JSSoup is slightly different though:soup.getText('|').split('|'), if you post this as a response I will gladly accept it.

Comment: Sounds fair, edited the answer added it as example.